# Can I use auth0 java sdk to verify an Okta token?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, auth0, okta, pkce

I have a grant/PKCE workflow for our SPA app to request an Access Token in Okta and have it sent to a resource server.

The SPA -> Okta part is settled, and sending the token to my Java resource server is simple. However, verifying the token is a little tricky for me.

If I simply use the great sdk provided by okta, `okta-jwt-verifier`, the process is fairly simple:

```
AccessTokenVerifier jwtVerifier = JwtVerifiers.accessTokenVerifierBuilder()
                .setIssuer("https://" + issuer + "/oauth2/default")
                .build();
```

The AccessTokenVerifier uses the issuer to gather the public keys transparently and validate a token.

However, our system has to support JWT from multiple sources and, as such we already have a dependency on the auth0 `java-jwt` v3.18 library. I was investigating ways to have auth0 get the public key and verify an access token but can't find a process for that.

What is the best way to create an instance of `com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier` to verify an Okta token?

Because of the logistics of what we are trying to support I need to avoid any starter libraries.

Answer (score 0):

To verify an Okta Access Token using the auth0 Java JWT library without using starter libraries, you can manually fetch Okta's public key and then create a custom JWTVerifier instance. Here's a general outline of the steps:

Retrieve Okta's public keys:
You can retrieve Okta's public keys using the JWKS (JSON Web Key Set) URL provided by Okta. This URL typically looks like: https://your-okta-issuer/.well-known/jwks.json.
Parse the JWKS and extract the public key(s):
Use a JSON parser to parse the JWKS response and extract the public key(s) associated with Okta. Each key in the JWKS represents a different public key that might have been used to sign Okta's JWTs.
Create a custom JWTVerifier:
Use the extracted public key(s) to create a custom JWTVerifier instance from the auth0 library.

Comment: maybe clean up your answer to make it more clear? It reads like an AI answer or a badly formatted copy-paste job as it stands...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, this does read like an AI generated answer. I should know- I asked there as well as here :-)

Answer (score 0):

It can help to first understand the process with a non-vendor library, such as [jose4j](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/src/master/), which will work for any standards-based provider:

The best practice is for your resource server to specify the expected algorithm, issuer and audience like this, while also providing a URL to a JWKS or issuer endpoint.

```java
var httpsJkws = new HttpsJwks(jwksEndpoint);
var jwksKeyResolver = new HttpsJwksVerificationKeyResolver(httpsJkws);

var claims = new JwtConsumerBuilder()
.setVerificationKeyResolver(jwksKeyResolver)
.setJwsAlgorithmConstraints(AlgorithmConstraints.ConstraintType.PERMIT, AlgorithmIdentifiers.RSA_USING_SHA256) 
.setExpectedIssuer("myissuer");
.setExpectedAudience("myaudience")
.processToClaims(accessToken);
```

I suspect that both Okta and Auth0 libraries are compatible with each other's authorization server, since normal JWT validation is only usually done as above. Just look for the above inputs and use them. You should then quickly get a working solution.

Comment: I think there is a bug with your code where you specify the audience.

Comment: Ha - you are right - I fixed it up :)